# Trying to execute command on router. C++ & libssh

Tags: c++, ssh, router, libssh

When I'm trying to run command on server (router) I get

> [C] Jan  3 05:32:16 ndm: bin::ndmc: invalid option "-c".

Most of the code is taken from the documentation.
There is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

string exec_ssh_command(ssh_session 
session, char *command) {
    string receive = "";
    int rc, nbytes;
    char buffer[256];
    ssh_channel channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
    if( channel == NULL )
            return NULL;

    rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
    if( rc != SSH_OK ) {
            ssh_channel_free(channel);
            return NULL;
    }

    rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, command);
    if( rc != SSH_OK ) {
            ssh_channel_close(channel);
            ssh_channel_free(channel);
            cout << "Error";
            return NULL;
    }
    nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    while (nbytes > 0)
    {
            if (write(1, buffer, nbytes) != (unsigned int) nbytes)
            {
                    ssh_channel_close(channel);
                    ssh_channel_free(channel);
                    return NULL;
            }
            nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }

    if( nbytes < 0 )
            return NULL;

    ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);

    return receive;
}

int main() {
    ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if( my_ssh_session == NULL ) {
            cout << "Error creating ssh session" << endl;
            return 1;
    }
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "192.168.1.1");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "admin");
    int rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if( rc != SSH_OK ) {
            cout << "Error with connecting" << endl;
            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            return -1;
    }

    rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, "pass");
    if( rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
            cout << "Error with authorization  " << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session) << endl;
            ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            return -1;
    }
    string ip_hotspot = exec_ssh_command(my_ssh_session, "show ip hotspot");
    cout << ip_hotspot << endl;
    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
    return 0;
}
```

My router is zyxel keenetic ultra.

uname -a: `Linux localhost 4.9.112-perf-gfb7749d #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 6 16:06:30 WIB 2018 aarch64 Android`

g++ -v:
`clang version 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)
Target: aarch64--linux-android
Thread model: posix`

I'm a beginner at libssh so please explain easier. :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the command-line `ssh` utility to run this command? Try running `ssh -v admin@192.168.1.1 'show ip hotspot'`. If you get the same ndm error from the router, you should contact the router manufacturer or some router-specific help forum.

Comment: I get the same error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Creeperasha This is for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58882863/6699433). I cannot comment when it's deleted. And yes, it looks better. Just wrap it into a minimal main function. I should be able to copy your code, compile it and get the same problem.

Comment: @klutt I've solved the problem. I've tried to use uninitialized COLOR_PAIR. Thanks for your help. When i tried to minimize my code, i found the problem.

Comment: @Creeperasha Which is exactly why we ask people to minimize the problem. It's an awesome debugging method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed. On version `3.3.2` of `Keenetic OS` it works fine.